# JOIN where t1.number is truncated to match t2.number

Tags: sql, database, foxpro

I'm trying to query two FoxPro databases so I can correlate a name to a number.  My issue is the number in Table1 is appended with `_D` but now in Table2.

I can get the results I need but not the `t2.name` field.

```
select 
t1.number,
t1.total,
t2.name 
from "Table1.dbf" as t1
LEFT JOIN "Table2.dbf" as t2 
ON trim(t2.number) = trim(left(t1.number,8))   
where t1.number like '%_D%'
```

**Table1**

| number | total |
| --- | --- |
| 572326_D | 198.45 |
| 584183_D | 154.36 |
| 585231_D | 135.23 |
| 561342 | 0 |
| 656714_D | 14.2 |

**Table2**

| number | name |
| --- | --- |
| 572326 | Google |
| 584183 | Twitter |
| 585231 | Space X |
| 561342 | GameStop |
| 656714 | Facebook |

**Expected Output:**

| number | total | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 572326_D | 198.45 | Google |
| 584183_D | 154.36 | Twitter |
| 585231_D | 135.23 | Space X |
| 656714_D | 14.20 | Facebook |

Comment: If your numbers are always 6 digit, then shouldn't your join be: `ON trim(t2.number) = trim(left(t1.number,6))` instead?

Comment: The structure of the table is so that it's actually a character field and not a number field so it pads the number with spaces at the front.  That's why the trim is there.  Actually I need an `LTRIM()` now that I typed that out :)

Comment: Sounds like an `left(trim(t1.number), 6)` is the right way to go then.

Comment: Got it @JNevill I did have to use `LTRIM()` but the ordering you have was the ticket.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JNevill for leading me to the solution.

```
select 
t1.number,
t1.total,
t2.name 
from "Table1.dbf" as t1
LEFT JOIN "Table2.dbf" as t2 
ON ltrim(t2.number) = left(ltrim(t1.number),6)
where t1.number like '%_D%'
```